# Beat extraction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3, signal-processing, wav

I have no experience in MATLAB and unfortunately my project is in MATLAB.

Basically the objective is to read a music source (preferably in mp3 format but .wav is also OK) into MATLAB and then apply a low pass filter in such a way that it filters everything except the beats. Then it should get the time at which each beat occurs and write the results to a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite a bit easier to work with .wav files I think, although Matlab way well have utilities for such things, in fact it does: [Reading .wav](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html)

The easiest way to implement a low pass filter is a moving average filter.

The simplest way to do this would be be to loop over the data and take an average of each group of n values. I'm not sure exactly how the cutoff frequency would depend on n, but you could experiment a bit.

Otherwise, I know that there is a signal processing toolkit for Octave and I think that Matlab has a built-in filter function: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Matlab_Filter_Implementation.html

A third way which is over the top, would be to perform an FFT and do the filtering in the frequency domain.

Once you have the low-frequency part of the signal you can check for samples that are above an amplitude threshold and output where in the data these were found.

Comment: Once you have the low part, you could use the auto-correlation function (which is with FFT I think) and find the period in the signal that way.

Answer (score 2):

30 seconds on google with the keywords "*beat extraction matlab*" yield the following two *code sources*:

1. [Music Audio Tempo Estimation and Beat Tracking](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/beattrack/)
2. [Beat This *A Beat Synchronization Project*](http://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects01/beat_sync/beatalgo.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you can use and state of the art Multi Feature beat tracker algorithm, the information of the algorithm is publish here:
J.R. Zapata, M. Davies and E. Gómez, "Multi-feature beat tracker," IEEE/ACM Transactions on Audio, Speech and Language Processing. 22(4), pp. 816-825, 2014. http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TASLP.2014.2305252

The Matlab implementation of the multifeature beat tracker is:
https://github.com/JoseRZapata/MultiFeatureBeatTracking